# How to add a picture to a proposal site on Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

I have created [a proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101153/pharmacy). How do I add a picture? I would like to add a picture of a capsule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to do so. Proposal pages don't support logos, etc. The description is also deliberately fairly short. Focus on gathering a community around your proposal and defining its scope. There will be plenty of time for images later. :)